# Unknown schematics

Tags: schematics, software

I'm trying to open some circuit schematics for some equipment I have in my lab. However, they were designed some time ago (2013) by an unknown technician with an unknown program.
There are two folders, one called SCH (with file types .SCH, .NET, .ERC, .CMP, .CLN) and one called PCB (file types .PCB, .NET, .LIB, .CMP, .LST, .CNF, .ERR). If i try to open the .SCH file it's a binary, apart from a "Schematic FILE" header.

Does anybody have any clue about what program might have been used to make these? I've tried to open them with the Allegro viewer, but with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up the [file extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sch_(file_extension))? It's not a binary, that's for sure :)

Comment: If Allegro viewer won't open the PCB file, then clearly it was created with a much earlier version or a different tool (and there are quite a few of them) and as 'pcb' as a file type makes sense for *any* tool to denote a PCB layout file it might be difficult to figure out which one of them it is.

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sch_(file_extension)  btw, easy to google.

Comment: @KingDuken: I think OP meant "binary" as opposed to ASCII, not binary as in "executable".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the .sch files I've got from nearly 20 years ago that start with Schematic FILE were created with OrCAD.

Comment: There are several free and open-source tools that you could try, see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software). Among the popular ones are EAGLE and KiCad.

Comment: Upon further research I agree with Finbarr, I think those are OrCAD design files.

Comment: https://www.pcengines.ch/orcadff.htm

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be helpful to open the files in a hex viewer utility that shows the binary file contents in hexadecimal and ascii format side by side. Some software packages may embed a vendor specific header or text string that can can help to identify the source tool set.

Comment: notepad++ can also open binary files and allows you to see any text within the binary